# how to calculate gridview for separate calculations in yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2, yii2-advanced-app

I want to separate the calculation of land cargo with air cargo on gridview. for example service_id land cargo = D2D and service_id air cargo = P2P. calculation of land cargo P x P x P / 4000 and air cargo P x P x P / 6000. I would like to find the city of origin to the destination, it will show land and air cargo rates on the gridview according to the calculation in gridview. I do not know how. thank you

```
    [
    'label' => 'Tarif',
    'format' => 'Currency',
    'value' => function ($model) {
        $volume = $model->rate * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['panjang'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['lebar'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['tinggi'] /4000 + $model->admin_fee; //$model->service_id=>['D2D']
        $volume = $model->rate * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['panjang'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['lebar'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['tinggi'] /6000 + $model->admin_fee; //$model->service_id=>['P2P']
        $mass = $model->rate * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['massa'] + $model->admin_fee;

        return $mass > $volume? $mass : $volume;
        }
    ],
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
[
    'label' => 'Tarif',
    'format' => 'Currency',
    'value' => function ($model) {
       $volume = 0;
       if($model->service_id == 'D2D') {
           $volume = $model->rate * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['panjang'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['lebar'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['tinggi'] /4000 + $model->admin_fee;
        } else if($model->service_id == 'P2P')
           $volume = $model->rate * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['panjang'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['lebar'] * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['tinggi'] /6000 + $model->admin_fee;
        }
       $mass = $model->rate * Yii::$app->request->get('TarifCargoSearch')['massa'] + $model->admin_fee;

       return $mass > $volume? $mass : $volume;
       }
],
```